# shift() method is modifying the another array that I don't want to modify

Tags: javascript, html

I only used shift() method for 'arr1[]', but that method modified 'arr2[]', too.
How can fix it?

```
<script>
        var arr1=['a','b','c','d','e'];

        var arr2=arr1;
        arr2.shift();
        alert(arr1);
        alert(arr2);
</script>
```

Comment: `var arr2 = arr1;` does not make a copy of the array.

Comment: You only have one array. `arr1` and `arr2` both have the same value: a reference to that array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to have a real assignation do

```js
var arr1=['a','b','c','d','e'];
var arr2 = Object.assign([], arr1);

arr2.shift();
console.log ('arr1:', JSON.stringify(arr1));
console.log ('arr2:', JSON.stringify(arr2));
```